# DrawerLayout not found in android-support-v13

Tags: android, android-support-library, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I've added android-support-v13 in my project and it gives me warning that

> WARNING: Found both android-support-v4 and android-support-v13 in the
>   dependency list. Because v13 includes v4, using only v13.

If I remove v4 from build path then DrawerLayout cannot be resolved to a type.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: You should delete v4 from lib folder as well, and then clean the project. It should the resolve the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I add v13 and v4 libraries in my project and because v13 includes v4 so it was conflicting with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Remove android-support-v13  from you libs folder if your don't need it.

Comment: I do need it due to FragmentPagerAdapter